# If we make a method synchronized then all the instance method will be locked or only the synchronized methods will be locked?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If we make a method synchronized then all the instance method will be locked while executing that method or only the other synchronized methods will be locked?

Comment: don't use the title as content at least add some more information

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the synchronized method is static then it will be synchronized for all instances, otherwise it will be synchronized for a specific object which called it.
if 1 object tried to access the synchronized method and the object has two calls to that method then the second call can't be proceed until the first operation is done